# analyzing of input text with tire gem

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I want to analyze a sentence using elasticsearch , as after analyzing elasticsearch returns tokens, I am able to do it using curl commad **GET /_analyze?analyzer=snowball&text=palying plays** , and result is obviously play,play.  But i want to this task in ruby using tire gem. 
Please help me how i can do it using tire gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tire API expects you to specify an index against which you want to perform the operation, so you have to cheat a little here:

```
Tire::Index.new('').analyze('playing play', analyzer: 'snowball')['tokens'].map { |e| e['token'] }

# => ["play", "play"]
```